# MySql safe transfer of value from one row to another

Tags: mysql, sql, transactions, innodb

I have a column called balance in a table.
the values represent real money. I need to tansfer safely certain amount from one row to another.

so the value is subtracted from row 1 and added to row 2. if row 1 balance is lower than the value the whole transfer operation should fail and both row ramin unchanged.

Since i'm using innodb I'm able to use a transaction to wrap the selects and updates
but it would be nice to have an efficient atomic operation to prevent locks for long time rollbacks if something fails.

Is there an efficient way updating those two rows?

Comment: Giving an example would be awesome.

Comment: If you've got the primary keys for both rows before you start, it's isn't going to take long enough for a lock to be problem. Putting it in a transaction will make it atomic. Post an attempt at we can go from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I developed my own solution:
Table name is Balance Columns are id and balance.
Precondition for this to work source and dest ids exist

```
UPDATE
  Balance
RIGHT JOIN
  (SELECT id FROM (SELECT :srcId AS id UNION ALL SELECT :dstId AS id) as v WHERE EXISTS(SELECT id FROM Balance WHERE id = :srcId AND balance >= :value)) AS ids ON Balance.id = ids.id
SET
  balance = balance + IF(ids.id = :srcId, -:value, :value)
```

parameter syntax is ":< paramter >" for php PDO::prepare

please check if any doupts

Comment: you can secure it more adding "AND EXISTS(SELECT id FROM Balance WHERE id = :dstId)" after the first exist
this will prevent vanish value when just srcId exists
the precondition is not needed anymore
PDOStatement::rowCount() should return 2 when transaction succeeded and value wasnt 0

Answer (score 3):

What you need to do is a sequence of operations like this.

```
 START TRANSACTION;
 SELECT (the row you're going to decrement) FOR UPDATE;
 SELECT (the row you're going to increment) FOR UPDATE;
 Your updates, whatever they are.
 COMMIT;
```

With the InnoDB or [Aria](http://mariadb.org/) storage engine, this will do what you need.  Here's an explanation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-locking-reads.html

It doesn't matter whether you `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` the row to decrement, or the row to increment, first, as long as you *always* select them in the same order. Otherwise your [philosophers will get hungry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dining_philosophers_problem).

Comment: thanks for the deadlock hint. I should always lock the lower id first.

I browsed a bit more and this seemed like an solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/188720/any-way-to-transfer-value-from-one-cell-to-another
I'm wondering what happens if one part update fails because the balance dropped below zero is the other part still changed? it's still one statement but is is still atomic?
I would really like to spare locks

Comment: You'd do best if you explicitly rolled back all transactions which fail (for example because of a negative balance).